# access 2010 append data into table without overwriting existing records

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Sorry for the long question/post but need some help as I've been searching for several days but havent found anything that helps.  Seems like it should be easy but..here goes

I have table1 in my (Access 2010) database that has exising records. I have another table2 that after I run a query, it first deletes the data in table 2, then imports new records into that table. I run the import into table 2 on a semi regular basis but have yet to copy all those records into table 1 successfully.

I need to copy only the records from table 2 to table 1 if the records don't already exist in table1. So, each time the query or vba code would run, it would be continuing to grow table 1 without duplicating existing data.

To clarify further, it's data from the Outlook GAL so each time table2 imports that data (lname,fname,phone,email) it needs to be added to table1, but only if it doesn't already exist in table 1.

I have a small start of SQL but cannot get it to work properly because I'm not sure how to add the other fields into this SQL statement properly (unfortunately I don't know a whole lot about SQL or creating an append query):

```
INSERT INTO [Current] ( FirstName )
SELECT DISTINCT tblglobaladdresslistimport.First
FROM tblglobaladdresslistimport LEFT JOIN [Current] ON tblglobaladdresslistimport.First =    Current.FirstName
WHERE Current.FirstName Is Null;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
INSERT INTO [Current](FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tblglobaladdresslistimport.First
    , tblglobaladdresslistimport.Last
    , tblglobaladdresslistimport.Phone
    , tblglobaladdresslistimport.Email
FROM 
    tblglobaladdresslistimport LEFT JOIN [Current] 
        ON tblglobaladdresslistimport.First = Current.FirstName
            AND tblglobaladdresslistimport.Last = Current.LastName
            AND tblglobaladdresslistimport.Phone = Current.Phone
            AND tblglobaladdresslistimport.Email = Current.Email
WHERE Current.FirstName Is Null
    AND Current.LastName Is Null
    AND Current.Phone Is Null
    AND Current.Email Is Null;
```

Adjust column names if I guessed it wrong. That assumed that you don't have primary key, so data in `tblglobaladdresslistimport` considered already exists if there is a row in `Current` having same value for all columns.

Comment: Thanks so much(just found your reply today!). I ran it but it still imported duplicates. Example: Assuming fields Last and First in both tables,so while SMITH JOHN already existed in 'current' table, it still imported Smith John into the 'current' table.(Note ALL CAPS vs mix of upper/lowercase) Perhaps if the query looked at the email field as the unique field, it wouldn't import duplicate records? The 'current' table's primary key is ID, tblglobaladdresslistimport has no primary key. I think query is close perhaps? Additional help appreciated! You can email me at knarlyd@hotmail.com